# Advice needed on using MacBook Pro 2019 screen as external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have an Intel MacBook Pro 2019, and over the years it’s become more and more unreliable to the point where I can barely do anything without it overheating, it’s basically become e-waste. I was wondering if I could detach the display module and use some kind of adaptor(or just some solder with a microcontroller) to use the screen as an external display. I can’t seem to find any information on what I would need for this easily. Could anyone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Why not open it up, give it a good cleaning (blow the dust out) and re-apply the thermal paste to the CPU and GPU.  That thermal paste is now 4+ years old now.  Overheating laptops usually respond very well to this service.  Obviously, if you’re not technically oriented, a tech can do this relatively inexpensively.

Comment: Also see this similar question and answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/399763/119271

Comment: @Allan I don't want to continue using the macbook, I'm switching to a new laptop anyways and I can't find a controller board for the lcd. I appreciate the help, but I need to know where to go to find a specific annoying little controller board. I haven't been able to find any apple controller boards past 2013 and am wondering whether they even exist. It seems like a futile effort, so this post is just a last ditch effort.

Comment: Either way, you have to get the exact model number of the LCD so you can match the panel.  There’s no such thing as a “Retina LCD” (it’s marketing parlance), you need to get the PN# then match it with an LCD driver board.  You can only do this by disassembling the unit.